# Encoding Error in Json file when copied from Sharepoint to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I have a json file in sharepoint and I am using Logic Apps to get the json file and dump it into blob storage. Further I need to open that json file in Databricks python using this code

```
blobstring = blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(INPUTCONTAINERNAME, INPUTFILEPATH)
myJson = blobstring.decode('utf8')
data = json.loads(myJson)
```

When I try to open json in python it gives me the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)
```

After using the "utf-8-sig" as decode I get this error

```
JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 103775708
```

**IMPORTANT**: When logic app dumps the json from sharepoint on blob, lease state is **expired** on the blob storage. I downloaded the json from blob and uploaded the same file manually (it made the lease state **available**) and the python code opened the json perfectly.

I thought it was an issue with lease state so after logic app dumped the json on blob, I made the lease state available with code (so I don't have to download and upload again manually) and tried to open json but received the same errors again.

In my logic app I am using the **get file content** for getting the file content of the .json file and **create blob** for creating a blob with the file content.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your storage blob has some setting which caused the lease state to expired, the lease state will become "expired" just after acquire the lease. I test it in my logic app(get a file from sharepoint and create blob), its lease state is "available".

[image]
[image]

And it works fine when I want to get this file in code.